# Ionic 3 - After data load ngModel undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I'm a bit of a beginner in angular 4... tried to search for this many times in the past few months, but got no result, even though it seems the most simple thing.

It's an ionic app. User logs in, the whole user object is saved to localStorage. Have tried several plugins, but went with simple:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('User', JSON.stringify(user));
```

**user object structure:**

```
export class User {
constructor(
    public token?: string,
    public user_email?: string,
    public email?: string,
    public first_name?: string,
    public last_name?: string,
    public user_roles?: {
        ID?: number,
        caps?: {
            administrator?: boolean,
        },
        roles?: object,
    },
    public id?: number,
    public device_feedback?: boolean,
    public role?: string,
    public username?: string,
    public billing?: Address,
    public shipping?: Address
) {}
}

export class Address {
    first_name?: string;
    last_name?: string;
    company?: string;
    address_1?: string;
    address_2?: string;
    city?: string;
    state?: string;
    postcode?: string;
    country?: string;
    email?: string;
    phone?: number   
}
```

**settings.ts:** (I have added ngOnInit and this.platform.ready(){} because thought data is not ready or something...)

```
export class Settings implements OnInit{
 [other vars]

 user: User;

 constructor(public storage: Storage, private platform: Platform) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // this.storage.ready().then(() => {
    // this.storage.get("User").then((data) => {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        let data = window.localStorage.getItem('User');
        if (data) {
            this.user = JSON.parse(data);
            this.email = this.user.user_email;
            console.log('user', this.user);
            console.log('this.user.user_email', this.user.user_email);

        }
    });
}
```

**Settings.html**

```
<ion-content>
<ion-list padding>
    <ion-list-header>
        Title
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" fixed>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="in" type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.user_email" disabled="true"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

The user_email is displayed in the console.log, referenced as **this.user.user_email** and same property gives an error in the HTML... how is this possible? Same in the browser or the device: http://prntscr.com/i8rfhg
I have also tried with `user: any`, but got the same result...

How? Why? What am I missing?

Here's the ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.1
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.1
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 25.2.5
Node              : v6.11.0
npm               : 5.6.0
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the property user_email of your user object while it's null / before it's initialized.

Try:

```
user: User = {}; // initial value
```

Or:

```
<ion-list padding *ngIf="user">
    <ion-list-header>
        Title
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" fixed>Email</ion-label>
        <ion-input class="in" type="email" [(ngModel)]="user.user_email" disabled="true"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: *ngIf="user" did the trick at the end, although it required some work.. at first it didn't work, I've added an ngIf to every input, then undid my work, and suddenly it works... Cache or something...

Answer (score 1):

In `ngOnInit`, the callback for `this.platform.ready()` is executed asynchronously. Before that, `user` is undefined and `[(ngModel)]="user.user_email"` causes an error.

You can prevent that error with the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths). Since it works only for one-way data binding, you should split `[(ngModel)]` in its two parts, `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`. In addition to that change, you can keep the input element disabled until `user` is initialized, to prevent entering data that will be lost anyway.

```
[ngModel]="user?.user_email" (ngModelChange)="setUserEmail($event)" [disabled]="!user"
```

with the component method:

```
setUserEmail(value: string): void {
  if (this.user) {
    this.user.user_email = value;
  }
}
```

The code is illustrated in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yctbgg), where the `user` object is initialized after a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have instance of User in this.user.

```
export class User {
    public token: string;
    public user_email: string;
    public email: string;
    public first_name: string;
    public last_name: string;
    public user_roles : Object = {
        ID: null,
        caps: {
            administrator: false,
        },
        roles: {},
    };
    public id: number;
    public device_feedback: boolean;
    public role: string;
    public username: string;
    public billing: Address;
    public shipping: Address;

    public set(data:any){
        if(!data){
            return;
        }
        this.token = data.token;
        this.user_email = data.user_email;
        this.email = data.email;
        this.first_name = data.first_name;
        this.last_name = data.last_name;
        this.id = data.id;
        this.device_feedback = data.device_feedback;
        this.role = data.role;
        this.username = data.username;
        this.billing = data.billing;
        this.shipping = data.shipping;

        this.user_roles = data.user_roles;

    } }
```

and

```
export class Settings implements OnInit{  [other vars]

 user: User = new User(); constructor(public storage: Storage, private platform: Platform) { }

ngOnInit() {
    // this.storage.ready().then(() => {
    // this.storage.get("User").then((data) => {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.user.set(window.localStorage.getItem('User'));

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use export interface and class.

```
export interface UserCaps
        administrator: boolean;
}

export interface UserRole {
        ID: null;
        caps: UserCaps;
        roles: any;
}

export interface Address {
    first_name?: string;
    last_name?: string;
    company?: string;
    address_1?: string;
    address_2?: string;
    city?: string;
    state?: string;
    postcode?: string;
    country?: string;
    email?: string;
    phone?: number   
}

export interface User {public token: string;
    user_email: string;
    email: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    user_roles : UserRole;
    id: number;
    device_feedback: boolean;
    role: string;
    username: string;
    billing: Address;
    shipping: Address;
}

export class User {}
```

And i init my user with new Class()

```
user = new User();
```